# How to play MIDI with Android device?

Tags: audio

So I have an Android Galaxy S5 and I'm wondering - is there a MIDI player that I can use for my MIDI files?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes there is try using Fun Fun [MIDI player available over the Google PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smilemelon.funfunmidiplayer&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

The basic music player app should play a MIDI file, mine does. It will play back using the on-board GM voices and you can make a playlist just as you would with MP3 files.